# Using UpdateCursor to update a field based on other field values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I've been trying to create a python script that will update certain fields in the arcgis attribute table. I have attempted to do this by using the update cursor to update a field based on another field value found in the same row.

Here is the code I used:

```
import arcpy

fc = "C:\Users\maureen\Documents\ArcGIS\EDRN\EDRN_LINK.shp"
fields = ["FID", "RIVERNAME"]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if  row[0] = 4401:
            row[1] = "Aire"
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Unfortunately, when I run this in ArcMap it returns the following syntax error:

```
Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 9)
```

Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong? I've researched this script a fair bit and can't see any obvious errors.

Comment: I suppose you ment if row[0] == 4401: // ... You forgot the double-equal-sign, that´s it I think

Comment: In addition to the answers below, make sure the "RIVERNAME" field is a text field.

Comment: from @Aaron above - I run into Subtypes sometimes and bang my head on the wall until I realize I'm looking for an integer value.  The == is the main problem though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For comparison of 'equals' you need to use a double equals sign '=='

```
if  row[0] == 4401:
        row[1] = "Aire"
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

A single equals sign is the assignment operator in python.